# Finding sequence of pairs with second element of previous pair matching first element of next pair

Tags: algorithms

I am interested in efficient ways of doing certain problem.

I have list of $n$ pairs, where $n$ is usually a few houndred thousands and each pair's element is an integer (let's assume it is integer from $0$ to $10000$) and I am trying to find a sequence such that it start and ends at chosen integer (we can assume it is eg. $0$) and second element of previous pair matches first element of next pair. So as an example, if we have set of pairs $\{(0,1), (1,3), (3, 2) (3,0)\}$ the valid sequence would be eg. $(0,1), (1,3), (3, 0)$. If there is a few answers then I can find arbitrary one. Moreover it is no certain  that my list of pairs actually has a solution. If it does not have solution, then the method should return no valid solutions.

I think that maybe some kind of dynamic programming could be useful here, but I don't really have an idea for something better than just checking all the options, which I am almost certain is quite bad. Do you have any interesting insight about this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integers of your problem form nodes, the pairs form directed edges. Then you can use Tarjan's strongly connected components algorithm to find the groups of nodes that form a cycle.